# Salesforce SSO with Microsoft AD : can some Salesforce users be under SSO control, and others not?

Tags: single-sign-on

We have some users worldwide who are connected to one Microsoft AD server, others who are not connected.

In Salesforce, can we have the first family of users use SSO under control of SSO, and the second family of users log in to Salesforce normally ?